# Cocoa orientation changes during applicationDidBecomeActive(), how to fix it?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa

I am coding a ViewController that controls a constraint working in a specific orientation, change its constant when orientation changed.

But when Application `resignActive` screen changes orientation twice, so constraint works weird.

Code:

```
private func updateforecourtHeightConstraint() {
    // TODO: This function just work for portrait orientation 'cause ios change orientation during resignActive/becomeActive
    let screenPortraitHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height > UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width ? UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height : UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width
    forecourtHeightConstraint.constant = screenPortraitHeight - 80
    rootTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(forecourtHeightConstraint.constant, 0, 0, 0)
    print(UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation.isPortrait)
}
```

On iPad Mini 2 device output

```
#App started
true
true
#resignActive
false
true
#resignActive
false
true
```

Thanks